# when removing element from form array with react-final-form, the displayed value of the <input> does not update, but final-form data object does

Tags: react-final-form, final-form, react-final-form-arrays

This is a bizarre situation. I have simplified an example of react-final-form-array that allows me to add elements to my form, and i can extend an array of objects. It is very similar to the simple example provided by react-final-form-arrays. The array works just fine, but the issue im having is that when i try to REMOVE a specific element, the actual value displayed in the inputs doesnt change. So for example, with images:

[image: basic form arrays example]

Here we can see i can add customers to a list, which makes an array of objects. This works great. Now, let's say i want to get rid of the first element. i click the X, and what happens?

[image: removed element from list]

Here we can see that the form data properly removed the first element i wanted to remove, however, the actual value DISPLAYED on the inputs is still John Doe, though the form knows it's Mary Jane. When i click on the inputs, they seem to update to the correct values. But this is not what should be happening.

The STRANGEST thing though, is that i made a codesandbox you can see here https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-wilson-5xlqq

It has the exact same code I have on my app, and it works as expected! So i cant even recreate the bug and i made sure the dependencies are the same versions im working with. I can only recreate it in my own setup, and i dont understand why that is.

I tried with chrome, safari and firefox and they all seem to be doing the same thing on my computer and i even tried on my phone by connecting to my react server that runs on my laptop, and they all show the same behavior.

I dont know what i could be, versions, react, if anyone has any idea or has had a similar issue in the past, PLEASE HELP. I won't paste my code here so as not to bloat this post, but you can see it's literally the exact same code in the sandbox i linked above.

**EDIT:** I want to point out another bug that occurs, and thats once i remove the first element, if i try to edit it, it pushes another field into the array with the input i just added, as if it were bound or something. I wish i could recreate it on codesandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting your node_modules folder and reinstalling them. Are you seeing any errors in your console log?

Comment: oh my god that worked! i cant believe i didnt think of just "turning it off and on again", i wasnt getting any errors, and i have no idea why it was doing this, but that seemed to have fixed it! thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: If you're experimenting with Final-Form and switching between version, you'll come across issues like this. If you're not on bleeding edge versions, you will run into upgrade issues since plugin versions are not aligned with Final-Form.

Comment: i hadnt really switched between any versions, i tried it once i saw the issue, but i hadnt actually changed versions. I ended up  upgrading it afterwards to try it as a solution. Im glad this solved it